# JavaFX - parameters of anonymous Circle class

Tags: javafx, anonymous

I have a class: MyCircle. This is the constructor:

```
public MyCircle(Node view) {
        this.view = view;
}
```

The instantiation in the other class:

```
Pane root = new Pane();
MyCircle obj = new MyCircle(new Circle(300, 200, 30, Color.BLUE));
root.getChildren().add(obj.getView());
```

**How can I get/set the parameters of Circle?** 
The `obj.getRadius()` can't work because the result is 0.0

Comment: The class `Circle` has a method `getRadius()`. Your `obj` is of class `MyClass`, which I can't tell if it has the method `getRadius()`. If it hasn't you could write a method `getRadius()` that calls the `getRadius()` method on `this.view`. (You'll have to cast it though...)

Comment: The view object is a Node, not a Circle. The Node has no method getRadius(). Therefore i can't write method getRadius() in the MyCircle class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Circle circle = (Circle) obj.getView();
circle.setRadius(50.0);
```

The point here is, that you store the Circle as a Node object. So you need to get the Node object and cast it to a Circle to set the radius.

Check, if you can store the Circle as a Circle instead of a Node. This makes life much easier and avoids instanceof checks or ClassCastExceptions.

Comment: The casting is the key! Thank you! 
I can make progress in my program!